# check for non ascii characters in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, non-ascii-characters

i have a result string that sometimes hold non ascii values. These non ascii values cause trouble so i need to check for their presence in the result string.

i tried with these two methods

```
if (regexpi(result , ^\s\x{20}-\x{7e}))
display('non ascii');
end
```

and

```
if any(result  < 128)
else
display('non ascii');
end
```

but it didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

small tweak to the above:

```
if all(result  < 128)
else
display('non ascii');
end
```

or

```
if any(result  > 127)
display('non ascii');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`regexprep` can be used to find and remove the non-ascii characters. For example:

```
out = regexprep(result, '[^0-9a-zA-Z.\s]+', '')
```

See the comments by @amro in [Remove non ASCII characters in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355697/remove-non-ascii-characters-in-octave)