# Detect and Convert non-ascii characters to ascii characters using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am extracting text from html webpages using matlab and have been successful in doing so. Please check my relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811990/extract-only-words-from-a-cell-array-in-matlab). However I am facing some problems. Suppose I am given these words -

```
{'ãmber' 'øøøùˆ' 'øùøøøùšø'}
```

I need to extract only the words. I need to change the non-ascii characters like as in `'ãmber'` to `'amber'`. Is there any way to detect non-ascii characters line `ã` and change it to its ascii counterpart `a` using matlab.

Comment: how should matlab know their counterparts? Is there any official conversion table to apply?

Comment: I have no idea hence the question. Sorry.

Comment: Well, some research on your side is required. I wouldn't know how to translate a greek phi into an ascii character.