# Remove non ASCII characters in octave

Tags: string, matlab, replace, octave, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to remove non ASCII characters read from a data file using OCTAVE but I can't make it work. I tried getting the ASCII codes of these "weird" characters and they do have random ASCII codes. An example string of characters is this:

> asdqwФЕДЕРАЛЬ234НОЕ234 АГЕНТСqewwqedasТВО ПasdsadО ОБРАasdasdЗОВАНИЮ
>   Госудаsadasdsagwfрственная акадеasdмия профессиональной п

Do you guys have any suggestions on how can i remove the non ASCII characters from this string? Or better yet, how will I be able to determine if a given string has non ASCII characters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you could do it fairly easily using regular expressions. Here is a C# example but the actual regexp part should be the same. You just have to call it from Octave instead of C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303435/1011724

Comment: i started studying octave just today.. so i don't know how to implement that yet :/

Comment: see `regexprep`: [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFregexprep). That would be: `out = regexprep(str, '[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '')` where `str` is your input string.

Comment: There's also the `isstrprop` function which can be of help.

Comment: I generally use [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python) as a playground for learning/testing regular expressions. Python's regex is pretty much the same as MATLAB/Octave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all non ASCII chars in the range of 0..127 decimal use

```
a = "asdqwФЕДЕРАЛЬ234НОЕ234 АГЕНТСqewwqedasТВО ПasdsadО ОБРАasdasdЗОВАНИЮ Госудаsadasdsagwfрственная акадеasdмия профессиональной п";
a(! isascii (a)) = []
```

which gives

```
a = asdqw234234 qewwqedas asdsad asdasd sadasdsagwf asd
```

and if you just want to check if there are non ASCII chars:

```
any (! isascii("foobar"))
ans = 0
any (! isascii("foobaröäüß"))
ans =  1
```